# How to constrain a MapBox map to show two markers with one marker in the center?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm trying to make a weather app where the user can click on a MapBox map and get weather information from the weather station closest to the user's click.
I've managed to set a marker where the user clicks and set another marker at the closest weather station location which is retrieved with a call to an API and have the map zoom in to show both markers with "map.fitBounds".

Right now I'm using the code below and it works as expected. It shows both the user's click and the found weather station with markers on a map that can accurately show both locations.
However, I would like to show a map where the user's click is centered and the map is zoomed to the right level to show the nearest weather station.

I've been wondering if I should calculate a third arbitrary point that is directly opposite the found weather station in relation to the user's click. Or is there a simpler and more direct solution?

```
coords.push([usrLngLat.lng, usrLngLat.lat]);
coords.push([wsLngLat.lng, wsLngLat.lat]);

var bounds = coords.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
    return bounds.extend(coord);
  }, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coords[0], coords[0]));

  map.fitBounds(bounds, {
    padding: { top: 75, bottom: 30, left: 90, right: 90 },
  });
```